# cygwin not recognizing paths with spaces in them

Tags: windows, cygwin

This is really strange. `cgypath` is returning paths with spaces in them, and when I try to `cd` to them, they fail as not being able to be found. I also notice this strange behavior with `pwd`. Observe this:

```
MyUser@MyMachine /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45
$ pwd
/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45

MyUser@MyMachine /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45
$ cd /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45
-bash: cd: /cygdrive/c/Program: No such file or directory

MyUser@MyMachine /cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 9):

You need to escape your spaces with backslashes or quote your paths:

```
cd /cygdrive/c/Program\ Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45
```

or

```
cd "/cygdrive/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45"
```

This is because commands take multiple arguments. The arguments are separated by spaces, so the command line thinks you pass the argument `/cygdrive/c/Program` and the argument `Files/Java/jdk1.6.0_45` to the command `cd`.

Comment: Sorry I didn't include an example usage of cygpath, but it does contain quotes. I'm curious though, should pwd print a path that is accessible without alteration?

Comment: Well, that means your example in your question is wrong, because in your example you don't use quotes.
I'm currently not on windows, so I can't check cygwin, but on Mac, this works fine:

Kay@Kays-Mac-Pro:/Volumes/xbmc/System Volume Information/
> cd "\`pwd\`"
Kay@Kays-Mac-Pro:/Volumes/xbmc/System Volume Information/
> cd "\`pwd\`"/../
Kay@Kays-Mac-Pro:/Volumes/xbmc/

Comment: Oh I get it now. The quotes need to be on the output and not on the input (to the cygpath command) only. Since the *output* has unescaped spaces.

Comment: @Zombies This comment should be an answer, you just saved me hours of pain